# Message processing stalls/pauses for a brief period randomly in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have an application that uses spring integration framework for message processing (Gateway -> Transform -> Service Activators). One of the issues that I am facing is that there is a considerable amount of delay, that varies from few milliseconds to few seconds, to process messages. The lag is not consistent, it appears that the messages are held up and processed at once in a burst.

I tried profiling the application using YourKit but I couldn't find any deadlocks or blocked threads. Turning on DEBUG logs for org.springframework.integration didn't give much information either. Here is the spring integration xml:

```
    <int:gateway service-interface="com.test.MessageGateway"
            id="msggateway" default-request-channel="msginputchannel" />

    <int:channel id="msginputchannel">
            <int:queue capacity="5000" />
    </int:channel>

    <int:bridge id="msginputbridge" input-channel="msginputchannel" output-channel="msgchannel">
            <int:poller fixed-delay="100"/>
    </int:bridge>

    <int:channel id="msgchannel">
            <int:queue capacity="5000" />
    </int:channel>

    <int:transformer input-channel="msgchannel"
            output-channel="msgPubSubchannel" id="msgtransformer" ref="msgserializer" method="serialzeTo" >
            <int:poller fixed-delay="100"  />
    </int:transformer>

    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="msgPubSubchannel" />

    <int:bridge id="msgQueueSystembridge" input-channel="msgPubSubchannel" output-channel="msgQueueSystemqueuechannel"/>
    <int:channel id="msgQueueSystemqueuechannel">
            <int:queue capacity="5000"/>
    </int:channel>

    <int:service-activator id="msgQueueSystempublisher" ref="msgQueueSystemadapter" input-channel="msgQueueSystemqueuechannel" method="publish" >
            <int:poller fixed-delay="100"/>
    </int:service-activator>

    <int:bridge id="msgbridge" input-channel="msgPubSubchannel" output-channel="msgFileSystemchannel"/>
    <int:channel id="msgFileSystemchannel">
            <int:queue capacity="5000"/>
    </int:channel>

    <int:service-activator id="msgfilewriter" ref="msgadapter" input-channel="msgFileSystemchannel" method="publish" >
            <int:poller fixed-delay="100"/>
    </int:service-activator>
```

Any pointers on how to go about debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a lot of `QueueChannel`s and all their polling tasks are based on the default `TaskSheduler` with the pool of threads as just `10`. So, it really might be as a bottleneck for you that all the task just share only those 10 threads.

You may consider do not use so much queues in between: I don't see reason to queue on all the steps in the flow.

On the other hand you can increase that pool size to a desired number using an integration `spring.integration.taskScheduler.poolSize` property: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/whats-new.html#x51.-global-properties

Comment: Thanks @Artem, the bridge+queue channels were added based on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44136105/1257065 to improve performance in my use case. I will take a look at the pool size configuration. Could you recommend ways to monitor the message flow and pinpoint the exact bottleneck?

Comment: The only way is to measure `preSend()` and `postReceive()` for messages on all those channels in logs. The Micrometer metrics can also help with that for monitoring: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#metrics-management

Comment: `>were added based on this ` - the point is there is no need for a thread hand-off on **every channel**, you generally only need one such channel, unless the flow has a great deal of complexity.

Comment: @ArtemBilan - Sorry about the delay in getting back. I have multiple such spring integration pipelines(xmls) running in a single jvm. Will the default TaskSheduler be independently created for each of the pipelines or is it one per process? Also, could you please provide a document that can help with XML configuration?

Comment: I missed the log entry, `[org.springframework.integration.config.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor] No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created` I have added 
 a bean `<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="50"/>`  to the context to increase the pool size.

Comment: This change appears to have fixed the performance issues that I was seeing. Thanks @ArtemBilan